# Unable to get the position of a character within my string using strpos

Tags: php

Good day,

I have the following string : 
[Star]ALERT[Star]Domoos detects blabla[blabli]

For strange reasons, the code below does not detect the star at the very first character. I read in the php documentation that the first character has an index of 0. However, if I am looking for the '[', the function works very well.

What I am trying to achieve is to ensure that the first character of my string is really a * (star). Strangely, if I enter $pos1 = strpos($inputString, '*', 1), the star shown at position '6' would be returned.

I don't quite understand why my code does not work as expected (i.e. does not enter into the 'true' condition)

```
$inputString = '*ALERT*Domoos detects blabla[blabli]';
$pos1 = strpos($inputString, '*', 0);

if ($pos1 == True)
{
echo 'position' . $pos1;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion that would help me to overcome this issue?

Thanks a lot for your appreciated support.

Comment: You could alternatively use `substr($inputString,0,1);` to extract the first character, then test this instead of finding the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change condition to

```
if ($pos1 != False)
{
    echo 'position' . $pos1;
}
```

as `strpos` will return position at (integer) or False

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the
>   haystack string.

In your test case, the numeric position is `0` and `0 != true`.

Also see the warning in the manual:

> Warning This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

So the condition you really want is:

```
if ($pos1 !== false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need strpos. As string is an array of characters so you can do like this

```
$inputString = '*ALERT*Domoos detects blabla[blabli]';
$compare_char= $inputString[0];
if($compare_char=="*"){
    //do something.
 }
```

As i suppose it is fast too rather than on searching through strpos

Answer (score 1):

Actually issue is that when you are looking at 0 position the value which you get is 0 and when you are checking that in `if condition` with True, it will always fail because **0 will be evaluated as False**. To resolve this you can use

```
if($pos1 !== False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns `false` if there is no existence of what you search. So make a check like the following:

```
$inputString = '*ALERT*Domoos detects blabla[blabli]';
$pos1 = strpos($inputString, '*', 0);

return $pos1 !== false ? 'position ' . $pos1 : '..';
```

Answer (score 0):

$pos1 returns 0 and this is treat as False so we cant take it as True so we can use here isset function.

```
$inputString = '*ALERT*Domoos detects blabla[blabli]';
 $pos1 = strpos($inputString, '*',0);

if (isset($pos1))
{
   echo 'position' . $pos1;
}
```